# Org plot table : wrong type argument listp hline

Tags: org-table

I learn org mode following the documentation, I try to plot an array with gnuplot but get the error `Wrong type argument: listp, hline`. Where does it come from ?

Here is the array :

```
#+PLOT: title:"Test" ind:2 deps:(3) type:2d with:histograms set:"yrange [0:]"
|---+-------+--------+-------------|
|   | index | number | number / 10 |
| / |     < |      < |             |
|---+-------+--------+-------------|
|   |     1 |    100 |          10 |
|   |     2 |    200 |          20 |
|   |     3 |    300 |          30 |
|   |     4 |    400 |          40 |
|   |     5 |    500 |          50 |
|---+-------+--------+-------------|
|   | total |   1500 |         150 |
|---+-------+--------+-------------|
#+TBLFM: $4=$3/10
```

I get the same error if I remove the last column (since it plots only 2d).

*Edit :*
I know have corrected the table according to the suggestion :

```
#+PLOT: title:"Test" ind:1 deps:(3) type:2d with:histograms set:"yrange [0:]"
| 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 200 |
| 3 | 300 |
| 4 | 400 |
| 5 | 500 |
#+TBLFM:
```

And get the error `Key sequence C-c SPC l starts with non prefix key C-c SPC`

Comment: The code shows that `org-plot/gnuplot` is very strict about the format of the table. It does not admit the format line before the hline of the header nor any other hlines below the header. There may be a hline at the top of the table and one hline directly following the one-line header and no other hlines at all.

Comment: I have another error, added to the post.

Comment: Make sure that the column in deps actually exists. Don't use histograms with numbers only.

Comment: You can see what org-plot/gnuplot sends to gnuplot in the `*gnuplot* Comint` buffer. This gives a good hint what actually goes wrong.

Comment: I have copied the same example as the one from the documentation and I still get this message. It seems that org try to launch a command with a keybindings prefixed with `C-c SPC` and it's not a valid prefix for my emacs... I have no `*gnuplot*` buffer.

Comment: Do you have `gnuplot-mode` installed? It is available via melpa. Try to start org-plot/gnuplot via `M-x` `org-plot/gnuplot`.

Comment: Yes I have it installed, I also try to run the command via `M-x org-plot/gnuplot` but it act in the same way.

Comment: Cannot reconstruct this problem. Sorry. Try to start your emacs with `emacs -Q`, i. e., without your customization, and test again.

Comment: It works with the prefix `C-c SPC` added. I'll keep it but don't know why it's not added by default since it is required...

Comment: Then write this as your own answer and accept it. Add the output of `org-version` and `emacs-version` and maybe your operating system. Also add the comments about `hline` in your answer becasue this is the actual summary of your question. Thanks in advance, Tobias.